# Converting Anonymous Function to 5.2 create_function

Tags: php, anonymous-function, create-function

I'm attempting to convert:

```
usort($discounts, function ($a, $b) use ($c, $d){

    $value1 = $c->do_action($a, $d, $d->value);
    $value2 = $c->do_action($b, $d, $d->value);
    return $value1 == $value2 ? 0 : ($value1 > $value2 ? 1 : -1);
});
```

Into a function that can be used in 5.2

Which so far I assumed I could do like this:

```
create_function( '$a, $b use ($that, $d)', ' $value1 = $c->do_action($a, $d, $d->value); $value2 = $c->do_action($b, $d, $d->value);return $value1 == $value2 ? 0 : ($value1 > $value2 ? 1 : -1);');
```

but you can't do `use($c,$d)` inside the first param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not an ideal solution you should be able to use the `global` keyword to accomplish what you need:

```
create_function( '$a, $b', ' global $c, $d; $value1 = $c->do_action($a, $d, $d->value); $value2 = $c->do_action($b, $d, $d->value);return $value1 == $value2 ? 0 : ($value1 > $value2 ? 1 : -1);');
```